# php mysql echo | How to inherit colors from a submit form?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, colors

I'm having some real trouble finding information on this topic and I would be very appreciative for any help.  In short I have a form where users select a category from a drop down list, enter some contents, and hit submit which goes to SQL.  Each category in the dropdown is color coded:

```
<option STYLE="color: #00CC66;" value="Option_1">Option_1</option>
<option STYLE="color: #0066CC;" value="Option_2">Option_2</option>
<option STYLE="color: #996633;" value="Option_3">Option_3</option>
```

etc

Then I have a php that pulls up the stored submitted data (categories and contents) into a table on that same page sorted by date.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","myuser","mypassword","mydb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mytable order by date DESC");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Contents</th>
<th>Date/Time</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['category'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['contents'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

My question is, when echo places the information in the table, is there a way I can get 'category' showing up in the same colors as the user form? (IE, on the table, Option_1 would show up as #00CC66, Option 2 as 0066CC, etc...)

Basically I want the actual category text on the fetched table to display the same as it is in the drop down form. I don't mind if I need to manually set each one as the categories are limited, I just have no clue where to begin on this one.  Appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: Maybe CSS classes is what you're after? The question is a bit unclear...

Comment: Maybe something to the affect of `echo "<td class='your_class'>" . $row['category'] . "</td>";` yet as stated, question is a bit unclear.

Comment: To try to clarify, the user has a dropdown box and a text box.  In the dropdown box they can select let's say "beef" or "lettuce." The actual text for "beef" in that dropdown is colored brown, and Lettuce is colored green.  Then they can enter how it tastes.  Once they hit submit it puts it into a table on the page that reads

Beef - Tastes great
Lettuce - Tastes like crap (or whatever they said.)

I want the beef and lettuce in that table to show up as Brown or Green like they do in the dropdown box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you would need to either change the value of the select box to the colour or manually do it like this:

```
function getColor($strOption)
{
   switch ($strOption)
   {
       case "Option_1":
       return "#00CC66";

       case "Option_2":
       return "#0066CC";
       #etc
    }
}
```

Then in your while loop:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><font color='".getColor($row['category'])."'> " . $row['category'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['contents'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
```

Comment: Oh nice!  Gonna try this now

Comment: Well, I've got the function in there (placed it just below $result if that's right)  but the echo line seems to break the whole table, nothing appears when it's inserted.

Comment: @sylcat I believe there's a mistake in `echo "<td><font color='".getColour` - should probably be `echo "<td><font color='".getColor` because of the function's name `function getColor($strOption)`

Comment: Haha that was it!  Man, how destructive 'u' can be ;]

Thanks guys, you're great!

Comment: @sylcat You're welcome. I edited the answer at the same time to reflect the changes.

Comment: @sylcat Also consider accepting the answer to close the question and give rep to the person who answered. Click on the white checkmark to the left of the answer till it turns green.

Comment: Ah, oops! I'm British, we use "colour" but HTML needs "color", must've got mixed up there! Good spot @sylcat