# I need to show items from a database in a table, how should I approach this?

Tags: php, mysql

49I need help understanding the approach to take with a problem. I have a data base that contains the fields id, LastUpdate, member_name, member_extension (phone ext), member_account_id, queue_account_id.

```
| id | LastUpdate  | member_name | member_extension | member_account_id | queue_account_id |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 2013-10-15  | John Smith  | 2750             | 1195              | 1105             |
| 2  | 2013-10-15  | Bill Jones  | 2749             | 1172              | 1248             |
| 3  | 2013-10-15  | Bill Jones  | 2749             | 1172              | 1105             |
| 4  | 2013-10-15  | Fred Black  | 2745             | 1195              | 1105             |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My problem is I need to show in a table the member_account_id's of each member in a queue. For instance queue_account_id 1105 has member_extensions 2450, 2741 & 2745 listed, I need to show those extensions in a table cell. I'm using php and mysql to access database. How do I approach this?

**EDIT:** Here is the table I need to display, I have all of it working except the techs logged in part. i guess my main problem is understanding how to get the queried tech identity data into the techs logged in field.

```
| Queue    | Calls | % total calls  | answered by us| % answered by us| abandoned | % abandoned | Redirected | % Redirected | Techs Logged In |   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Premium  | 1     | 9%             | 0             | 0%              | 1         | 100%        | 0          | 0%           |                 |
| Standard | 2     | 0%             | 1             | 150%            | 0         | 0%          | 1          | 50%          |                 | 
| Queue 2  | 1     | 0%             | 1             | 100%            | 0         | 0%          | 0          | 0%           |                 | 
| Queue 3  | 7     | 64%            | 4             | 57%             | 3         | 43%         | 1          | 0%           |                 |                  
| Totals   | 11    | 100%           | 6             | 55%             | 4         | 36%         | 1          | 9%           |                 |                  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: *"I need to show those extensions in a table cell."* - What kind of table, an "HTML" table?

Comment: This is pretty basic. Any PHP & MySQL tutorial should cover this. Have tried anything yet?

Comment: Sounds like homework :)

Comment: Yes, HTML table cell, the table currently displays # call, calls abandoned, calls redirected per queue. I need to add a cell that displays the ext numbers of techs in a queue

Comment: Not homework Brian but i wish it had been.

Comment: @ScottMorrison Have a look at this then, pretty sure that's what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19120244/1415724 (2nd body of code)

Comment: @ScottMorrison Please don't use ALL CAPS in your question. It's considered shouting here.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear whether this is a php or mysql question.

You can gather the items with a mysql query, as follows.

```sql
 SELECT member_account_id, member_name, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(queue_account_id 
                        ORDER BY group_account_id 
                        SEPARATOR ', ') AS ids
   FROM yourtable
  GROUP by member_account_id, member_name
```

Comment: Thanks Ollie, in this, does ids contain the data I can explode into the table? I ran this and it contains BLOB, I'm not sure what that is but I'm thinking it's an object containing the data??

Comment: The `ids` column in this result set should be a string containing a bunch of comma-separated ids.  For example `2450, 2741, 2745`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
t1.queue_account_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.member_extension) member_extensions
FROM tblname t1
INNER JOIN tblname  t2 USING (queue_account_id)
GROUP BY t1.queue_account_id
```

This is how you would present it in your scenario:

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('dbname');

$sql = 'SELECT
    t1.queue_account_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.member_extension) member_extensions
    FROM tblname t1
    INNER JOIN tblname t2 USING (queue_account_id)
    GROUP BY t1.queue_account_id';
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

echo '<table border="1">';

while ($rs = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $rs->queue_account_id . '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo '<ul>';
foreach (explode(',', $rs->member_extensions) as $extension) {
    echo '<li>' . $extension . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: I understand how I can query for them, but how do I get them in a table cell? foreach loop?

Comment: if you have the combined member_extensions back you can just explode them by the separator (,) and do whatever you want with it. like in my case, i exploded the member_extensions and printed it out as a list.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```sql
SELECT queue_account_id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(member_extension) member_extension
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY queue_account_id
```

Output:

```
| QUEUE_ACCOUNT_ID | MEMBER_EXTENSION |
|------------------|------------------|
|             1105 |   2750,2741,2745 |
|             1248 |             2749 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/607da/2)** demo

Comment: Yes! That's the idea!

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT queue_account_id, GROUP_CONCAT( member_extension ) member_extension
        FROM currentTechs
        GROUP BY queue_account_id"); 
$sth->execute();
$sql = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo '<table border="1">';

try {
    //$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
    //$result = $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

    foreach ($sql as $rs) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $rs['queue_account_id'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
            foreach (explode(',', $rs['member_extension']) as $extension) {
                echo $extension . ", ";
            }
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        }

    echo '</table>';
    }
catch (PDOException $e) {
print $e->getMessage();
}
```